# Characterization of the resolvent of a bounded operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space  with inner product $\langle\cdot\;| \;\cdot\rangle$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$.

> If $A\in\mathcal{L}(E)$, why
>    \begin{align*}
> \rho(A):=\mathbb{C}\setminus\sigma(A)
> & = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\colon \exists d>0; \|(\lambda \mathrm{Id}-A)y\|\geqslant d\|y\|,\;\forall\;y\in E\\
>  &\phantom{+++}\;\hbox{and}\;\;\mathrm{dist}(x, \mathrm{Im}(\lambda\mathrm{Id}-A))=0\,\forall x\in E\;\}?
> \end{align*}
>   where $\mathrm{dist}$ is the distance induced by $\|\cdot\|$.

Comment: that looks more like the *complement* of the spectrum

Comment: are you sure that shouldn't be a $\rho$?

Comment: @Timkinsella You are right

Comment: What exactly do you have trouble with? Can you show one of the two inclusions $\subset$ or $\supset$?

Comment: An invertible operator has to be bounded below, and have dense range. How to show the density of the range? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second condition says the image of $\lambda I - A$ is dense. The first implies $\lambda I - A$ is injective and has closed image. So $\lambda I - A$ is a linear bijection. The first condition also implies its inverse is bounded.

Comment: Why the second condition give us the density of the image of $\lambda I - A$ ?

Comment: @Student in a metric space $d(x,A)=0 \iff x \in \overline{A}$.